# Export all information related to Contacts using List Manager

Tags: contact-facets, list-manager

**Environment**: Sitecore 9.3

I have a list of contacts based on both OOTB and custom facets. When you try to export a list using `List Manager`, it exports the following fields in CSV file: `Identifier`, `Source`, `Email`, `First Name` & `Last Name`.

How to extend the current functionality of `List Manager` to export the other information related to the `Contacts`? Other information like `Address`, `Phone Number`, etc.

Comment: You can try Sitecore Powershell Scripts (SPS) for this. One of the old url for mongodb https://jockstothecore.com/xdb-reports-with-powershell/

Comment: https://medium.com/@danjelv/list-manager-export-contacts-and-custom-facets-in-sitecore-9-51090331b96d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add OOTB Facet field to the CSV file:**

```
using Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web.Export;
using Sitecore.XConnect;
using Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model;

namespace YourProject
{
    public class PhoneNumber : IContactDataReader
    {
        public string FacetName => PhoneNumberList.DefaultFacetKey;

        public string Map(Contact contact)
        {
            var phoneNumberList = contact.GetFacet<PhoneNumberList>(PhoneNumberList.DefaultFacetKey);
            string phoneNumber = $"{phoneNumberList.PreferredPhoneNumber.CountryCode}{phoneNumberList.PreferredPhoneNumber.Number}";
            return phoneNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

**To add a Custom Facet field to the CSV file:**

```
using Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web.Export;
using Sitecore.XConnect;
// Add reference containing definition for Custom Facet

namespace YourProject
{
    public class CustomFacetField : IContactDataReader
    {
        public string FacetName => CustomFacetName.DefaultFacetKey; 

        public string Map(Contact contact)
        {
            var customFacet = contact.GetFacet<CustomFacetName>(CustomFacetName.DefaultFacetKey);
            string customFacetFieldName = customFacet.CustomFacetFieldName;
            return customFacetFieldName;
        }
    }
}
```

The **final step** is to patch the `App_Config/Sitecore/ListManagement/Sitecore.ListManagement.config` with your own config file.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <listManager>
      <export>
        <field name="PhoneNumber" type="YourProject.PhoneNumber, YourProject" />
        <field name="CustomFacetField" type="YourProject.CustomFacetField, YourProject" />
      </export>
    </listManager>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

For detailed explanation, check out this [article](https://sitecorify.com/list-manager-export-contacts-with-custom-facets/).